# Accelerometer Event Detection on STM32

Tags: c, embedded, accelerometer, microcontroller

I need to detect an accelerometer event when user hits the device on table/floor.

Device is having a STM32 low-power microcontroller at 8 MHz and an LIS3DH accelerometer.

The accelerometer is operating in +- 2G range. Sample numbers are signed 16-bit integers.

I have collected accelerometer data for such an event by reading from the accelerometer at 50 Hz. I have attached the graph of x, y and z samples. The "hit" event is clearly visible in the graphs, red dots on the time axis show the point when the event occurred. But I have no idea how to detect such event in code.

The DC offset changes for 3 axes according to orientation of device.

[image]

Again, sampled at 100 Hz, the graph is for the X axis only and shows 2 hit events. Such spikes will happen simultaneously on all 3 axes, but amplitude and direction may vary. The time scale is zoomed in, compared to the other graphs. Sampling at 100 Hz is not possible in the actual application code.
[image: X Axis Sampled @ 100 Hz]

The device orientation change and movements in hand of user causes a lot of signal variation. Below is a graph for the Y axis with hand movement, orientation change and hit event. Such changes will happen across all axes.

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you painted in (without covering the data) where you think the event occured. It's perhaps less obvious to a casual reader.

Comment: Try differentiating it again - take the difference between successive samples and graph that - you should see the jerk when the acceleration changes rapidly.

Comment: I have modified the graph ,there is a Red Dot over  those Points of Time when 'Hit" event occurred ,sudden Spikes are seen in x,y,z sample values,  the number of these spikes is equal to 'Hit" event recorded by me , and the Time gap between them is also same as Time Gap between "hit' events .

Comment: Some of the LIS accelerometers actually got the "hit" function built-in, giving an I/O interrupt whenever it detects a hit. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: The LIS3DH can be configured to generate an interrupt on click, double-click or inertial wake-up detection if accleration exceeds a threshold on the configured axes.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Martin James, you should measure the differences in accelerations between the current and last tick. You need to do this on each axis, because from your data, some of the hits don't affect every axis. One might suppose that you could use the total acceleration by using the sum of squares, but I don't think this will work.

To measure the difference, you will need to keep the last reading in a variable. You might need the previous two readings, depending on how fast the sampling rate is; if the rate is too high, then the differences may always be small. You should also keep a count of ticks since the last hit.

Then, when taking the current reading, compare the current readings with the previous readings. If the difference is above a threshold on any axis, mark it as a hit and reset the time_since_hit_count -- unless a hit happened recently. You want to avoid counting the same hit many times as the acceleration changes during a single hit. Your data suggests a threshold of around 5000.

If the difference is not above the threshold on any axis, increment the time_since_hit_count and replace the stored readings with the current ones.

(If you are storing the previous two hits, compare against each, and move the stored values appropriately.)

From your data, some hits take 3 ticks to occur, so you could discount hits if the time_since_hit_count is less than 5, say. That's 100 ms per hit. Depending on the application, that might be okay. A drum stick could bounce faster than that, but a finger probably not.

You'll probably have to experiment with the acc threshold and the hit count threshold as you collect data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also evaluate the embedded sensor functions:

- [wake up](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/blob/master/lis3dh_STdC/examples/lis3dh_wake_up.c)
- [double tap](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/blob/master/lis3dh_STdC/examples/lis3dh_tap_double.c)
- [single tap](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/blob/master/lis3dh_STdC/examples/lis3dh_tap_single.c)

Examples are from [STMicroelectronics sensors github repository](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers) and the embedded functionalities are described in the [device datasheet and application note AN3308](https://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/lis3dh.html#documentation).